# Create sf object from data frame with multiple coordinates | R sf

Tags: r, dataframe, r-sf

I want to create an sf object from a data frame that contains multiple coordinates under different columns for each row. In the repex below, each ID contains start and end coordinates for both latitude and longitude.

[image]

```
dfr <- structure(list(ID = c("1001A", "1002A", "1003A", "1004A", "1005A", 
"1006A", "1007A", "1008A", "1009A", "1010A"), StartLat = c(33.53418, 
33.60399, 33.40693, 33.64672, 33.57127, 33.42848, 33.54936, 33.49554, 
33.5056, 33.61696), StartLong = c(-112.09114, -111.92731, -112.02982, 
-111.92548, -112.04899, -112.0998, -112.09123, -111.9687, -112.05629, 
-111.98657), EndLat = c(33.53488, 33.60401, 33.40687, 33.64776, 
33.57125, 33.42853, 33.54893, 33.49647, 33.5056, 33.61654), EndLong = c(-112.09114, 
-111.93097, -112.03429, -111.93031, -112.04807, -112.09929, -112.09122, 
-111.97105, -112.0541, -111.98657)), row.names = c(3028L, 8618L, 
6322L, 1171L, 691L, 6590L, 2008L, 4552L, 2894L, 1909L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried using the sf package's `st_as_sf` function, but it yields an error:

```
dfr_sf <- st_as_sf(dfr, coords = c(c("StartLong", "EndLong"), c("StartLat", "EndLat")),
                   crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

```
Error in points_rcpp(as.matrix(cc), dim) : 
  dim(pts)[2] == nchar(gdim) is not TRUE
```

The start and end coordinates in each row define a road segment. All the coordinates should go under the geometry column in the final sf object so that these can be plotted as polylines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find an alternative solution with `data.table` and `sf` libraries. I hope I am not wrong: the lines appear in Arizona.

```r
library(data.table)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Reshape the data.table 'dfr' into long format
dfr2 <- melt(setDT(dfr), measure= patterns("Long", "Lat"), 
          value.name= c("Longitude", "Latitude"), na.rm=TRUE)[,variable:=NULL][]


# function 'rename_geom_col' to rename the geometry column of the 'sf' object
rename_geom_col <- function(x, new_name){
  current_name  <-  attr(x, "sf_column")
  names(x)[names(x)==current_name]  <- new_name
  st_geometry(x) <- new_name
  return(x)
}

# Convert the data.table 'dfr2' into the linestring 'sf' object 'results'
results <- dfr2 %>% 
  split(., by = "ID", keep.by = FALSE) %>% 
  lapply(., as.matrix) %>% 
  lapply(.,st_linestring) %>%
  st_as_sfc() %>% 
  st_as_sf %>% 
  st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
  mutate(ID = dfr2[1:(nrow(dfr2)/2),"ID"]) %>% 
  relocate(x, .after = last_col()) %>% 
  rename_geom_col(., "geom")


results
#> Simple feature collection with 10 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -112.0998 ymin: 33.40687 xmax: -111.9255 ymax: 33.64776
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#>       ID                           geom
#> 1  1001A LINESTRING (-112.0911 33.53...
#> 2  1002A LINESTRING (-111.9273 33.60...
#> 3  1003A LINESTRING (-112.0298 33.40...
#> 4  1004A LINESTRING (-111.9255 33.64...
#> 5  1005A LINESTRING (-112.049 33.571...
#> 6  1006A LINESTRING (-112.0998 33.42...
#> 7  1007A LINESTRING (-112.0912 33.54...
#> 8  1008A LINESTRING (-111.9687 33.49...
#> 9  1009A LINESTRING (-112.0563 33.50...
#> 10 1010A LINESTRING (-111.9866 33.61...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Please see if `dfr_line` is what you want. I think the idea is we need to create a point sf object first, and the convert it to linestring.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

dfr2 <- dfr %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c("Type", ".value"), names_pattern = "(^[A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+$)")

dfr_point <- dfr2 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")

dfr_line <- dfr_point %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")
```

Comment: It's not worth me posting a whole new answer, but `tidyr::pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = c("endpoint", ".value"), names_pattern = "(^[A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+$)")` can take the place of your `pivot_longer - extract - pivot_wider` sequence. You also don't need the `select` call since that column should get dropped when you summarize anyway

Comment: @camille Thank you for your suggestion. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @camille, good idea! would you mind to explain the function of `names_pattern = "(^[A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+$)" `, how it works and generate two columns names "Long" and "Lat"?

Comment: @Tenstu the regex will make 2 groups, each matching one capital letter followed by multiple lowercase letters. That gets you "Start" and "Lat", "End" and "Lat", etc. Here's a demo https://regex101.com/r/7Z5c9c/1. The docs for `pivot_longer` go into how the special flag `".value"` will create the Lat & Long columns based on the regex

Comment: @camille Thanks for your regex demon, I got it, and I read the docs which imply that Note the special name .value: this tells pivot_longer() that that part of the column name specifies the “value” being measured (which will become a variable in the output). In that way, does it mean the column name will be auto detect after the seperate (to genereate lat and long rather than start and end), what if it general a wrong name or can it be manual control?

Comment: @Tenstu I'm not totally sure what you mean but you make a regex pattern to match the way names in your data frame are structured and what pieces you want to extract from them. You should try the package examples to see how it works

Comment: @camille thanks for your advice. I just wonder how the "".value" will create the Lat & Long columns based on the regex", why it won't create start & long column? I read the examples through and found it might be the sequence order of `names_to = c("endpoint", ".value")`,  if change to the `names_to = c(".value", "Type")`, get column start & long.